# Can you call the same method on different threads?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio

Really noob question I know but I'm trying to understand how methods and threads work as an amateur programmer. I'm sure this is a fundamental lack of understanding on my part but hopefully some nice person can put me straight.

What I was wondering is if you call the same method multiple times using multiple threads do you create sandboxed versions of each method which act independently of each other or can they interfere with each other. For example I've knocked up some very simple code below to try to illustrate what I mean.

So in the example we have a method that is called when a button is clicked. It takes two numbers and feeds them into a second method that adds them together and returns the result. This seems straight forward. But imagine we wanted to do another calculation using the same method but we didn't want to wait for the first calculation to finish. We could invoke the method that adds the numbers on a separate thread so it doesn't hold up the UI thread. Cool. Ok but what if we do this twice? or three times?

What I'm trying to ask is when "doSum" is called the first time below the numbers passed into it are 10 and 20. The code runs the method on a separate thread and should return the answer 30. The second time it is called the numbers are 30 and 50 and the result should be 80. If for some reason the calculation in the first thread was still going on does it get overwritten when I call the same method a second time? Would result1 ever be in danger of being returned as 80 or 140?

Does this make sense to anyone?

```
public void onbuttonclicked(View v) {

int number1;
int number2;
int result1, result2, result3;


//first callculation --------------------------------------
number1 = 10;
number2 = 20;
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        result1 = doSum(number1, number2);
            }
    });
    t1.start();


//second callculation -----------------------------------
number1 = 30;
number2 = 50;
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        result2 = doSum(number1, number2);
            }
    });
    t2.start();

//third callculation -----------------------------------------
number1 = 60;
number2 = 80;
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        result3 = doSum(number1, number2);
            }
    });
    t3.start();


}


public static int doSum(int a, int b)
{
    int result = a + b;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The variables number1 , number2 and number3 should be *final*. Does your code compile?

Comment: or move them into class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are primarily 2 things you should know.

1. If 2 threads call the same method, each thread will have a different *Stack Frame* for the method. So, method local variables are thread safe. The changes made in local variables of one method will not interfere with other thread's changes.
2. You should (usually) worry about thread-safety / interference when you have a shared resource being modified by both threads.

PS : Your `doSum()` does very little processing. A smart JVM might actually *inline* the method.

Comment: As to 2, you should also worry if one thread modifies the number (the gui thread in this question), and other threads use the number. The numbers passed into doSum() are already subject to a race condition.

Comment: @minghua - I don't think his code would compile. The variables need to be *final*.  He doesn't have a race condition in his code.

Comment: Do you mean to say, there are different stacks for different threads for same method, that can be modified independently?

Comment: @Subhajit - There will be only 1 *Java Stack*. Each thread will have a *different Stack Frame* (to keep the state of variables) for each method it invokes.

Comment: I think you are probably right and that the code wouldn't compile but I was just trying to knock up something simple to illustrate what I was trying to ask. Hopefully this hasn't confused everyone.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, there is no problem with doSum().  It uses only the parameters passed and local vars.  So, doSum() has:

1) Code.  The binary instruction codes are thread-safe unless self-modifying, (never do that!).

2) Local vars and parameters.  On most architectures, this means register and stack storage. Since each thread has its own register set and stack, there can be no conflict.

Comment: Ok - there seems to be a bit of debate here. Martin - as the person with the most feedback I'm guessing I'm going to go with you and you seem to agree with Mr TheLostMind (the first answer) right? I was thinking of a scenario where you might call a function to ping an several IPs. Obviously response times could be varied but as long as variables are kept local you should be able to call the same method on different threads to ping multiple IPs without them interfering with each other?

Comment: @Regnodulous, Just add 100ms delay before calling doSum() in your t1. You will see if it is 30, 80 or 140.

Comment: @Regnodulous - you example as posted is fine, but that does not mean that there will be no issue with other functions with more scope. ICMP ping is one of those functions.  ping has no socket context and so, when several threads send pings and the gnips come in, the network stack cannot route the gnip to the originating thread.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Appreciate the help. Is there any way you know of of pinging multiple ips at the same time without holding up the ui thread?

Answer (score 0):

Those threads run independently thus the results shall be random, all depending the speeds of them. This is a typical race condition situation. Maybe you should read up about race conditions, it should not be difficult to understand.

By random it means your t1 could be calling doSum() at the point right after number1=30 thus the result1 shall be 50. That's just one example though.

Comment: There is no race in doSum().

Comment: When they reach the calling points to doSum() the arguments passed in will be random. It's the race between the three threads and the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Threads in java run independent ie. depend of how you configure. When threads come into picture, result always become unpredictable, means the result which you got first attempt, it won't get into second time.

In your case, onbuttonclicked() will handled/run by main thread, which will create other 3 thread. Its completely upto ThreadScheduler, which thread will run first. Because this operation happens very fast mean while initialization process might(not always) gets over.

So here, first thread may get result as 140. Its unpredictable.

Hope this help you.